# casting a list to object

Tags: android

I am trying to add an adapter to my activity so I can show a list of animals.

I am getting this error:

> ```
> 11-24 12:08:20.918: E/AndroidRuntime(6394): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.animals.Animal cannot be cast to java.util.Map
> ```

```
 package com.myapp.animals;

    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;


public class SlachtList extends Activity {
    static final String[] FROM = {AnimalData.C_BATCHNR, AnimalData.C_VOLGNUMMER};
    static final int[] TO = {android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2 };

    ListView list;
    List animals;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slacht_list);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        animals = ((AnimalApp) getApplication()).animalData.getAnimals();

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, animals, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, FROM, TO);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_slacht_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

animals is a List of animal objects. Appearantly the adapter wants a different type of object. I think that's the problem. Can anyone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should use custom adapter instead of SimpleAdapter, which really isn't good enough to handle objects, what you can do with SimpleAdapter is this (supposing you want to list animals by their names) :

```
 SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, GetSampleData(), android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, FROM, TO);
```

Use this method:

```
List<Map> GetSampleData()
{
 List<Map> list = new ArrayList<Map>();
 for(int i=0;i<animals.size();i++){
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("animalName", animals.get(i).getName());     
    list.add(map);
  }
 return list;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of SimpleAdapter is declared as

`public SimpleAdapter (Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to)`

and you are passing a plain list into it.

You list has to be something like

`List<HashMap<String, String>> animals;`

Comment: Though the other answer is more detailed, this doesn't make use of raw collection types.